# Deployment error for isCaseSensitiveDeterministicEncryptionEnabled (or isCaseInsensitiveDeterministicEncryptionEnabled) element in metadata

Tags: metadata-api

When I am trying to deploy the custom metadata for my Activity object (content of Activity.object) I am getting this error message:

`1.  objects/Activity.object -- Error: Error parsing file: Element {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}isCaseInsensitiveDeterministicEncryptionEnabled invalid at this location in type CustomField (line 64, column 58)`

At line 64 I have:

`<isCaseInsensitiveDeterministicEncryptionEnabled>false</isCaseInsensitiveDeterministicEncryptionEnabled>`

According to this link this issue should be already fixed: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mDQRQA2&title=metadata-change-when-deterministic-encryption-is-enabled

Does anyone know why I am still getting this error message?
Does anyone know how to solve this issue (without have to change the .object file)?

Best,

Comment: Are the source and target orgs at the same release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We saw this same error when the source sandbox is in Summer 18 and the destination is in Winter 19, even do we were deploying using the Summer 18 API to deploy. Seems to be a bug from Salesforce API that is not backward compatible.